# I want to make the menu sticky

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu, helix3

I'm using helix3 template and I want to make the menu sticky to the top of the page, and to change its style when scrolling.
how can I achieve that!

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [template demo](http://demo.joomshaper.com/2015/helix3/) and , I put together a quick solution using jQuery and CSS, but if your template has been customized, this might not work as expected:

**CSS**

```
.fixedMenu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 90) {
        jQuery('#sp-header').addClass('fixedMenu ');
    } else {
        jQuery('#sp-header').removeClass('fixedMenu ');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Having done a quick Google search (hint), I believe the Helix 3 templates supports a fixed/sticky header in the Template Options:

[image]

Comment: It didn't work! but thank you anyway.

Comment: Template is probably poorly made then. You need to reviews it's code and change it there directly.

Comment: i have changed the code and it worked, thank you!